# Can PHP global variables be set in another function, so you can call them?

Tags: php, function, global

I've started using "global" variables that I need in functions. Now that I work with [PDO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP#Development_and_community), I usually need to call the PDO connection as a global variable in my functions. But I usually have some more variables that I frequently use and I was wondering, can I somehow set all my global variables in a separate function and call that function from another function that needs the global variables?

Or do I need to use something like include?

```
global $pdo, $foo, $bar;
```

I know there is something called register global variables, but as far as I know that's not the road you want to take. Sure I can call my global variables in each function... I just thought I could call them from another function or something would be more easy. Sure it will be a bit irrelevant in some functions if I call a set of global variables, and I don’t use all of them. Any ideas or inputs on this? Which way is preferable?

Comment: `'I've started using "global" vars that I need in functions'`. [It is probably better if you don't](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Update* 
I just realized I didn't really answer your actual question: Though it is, technically, possible to set/add/reassign global variables from within a function, ***don't***, that way, madness lies. 
Imagine the following scenario: to use a group of db-related functions, you call this one `init_db` function, which sets up all of the required global variables. Great, you may be thinking. But between the time this function is called, and the first of your other functions is called, anything could've happened to those carefully prepared global variables.

So you'll end up with each of these function checking the global variables they need, and if one of them doesn't hold a value that makes much sense to them, you'll probably call `init_db` again. Over and over, working around code that is overwriting a vital component of your application. Effectively hiding bugs, and that's not even mentioning code injection attacks! 
Besides, think about this quote:

> Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place. Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are, by definition, not smart enough to debug it. — Brian Kernighan

Here are less than 15 lines of code. Keep in mind that a real application easily contains a thousand times more code, spread out over multiple files, and answer me this: Will you be able to predict what any one variable will hold, at any given time?

```
function initGlobals()
{ // Not possible:
    global $newGlobal;
    $newGlobal = 123;
}

function foobar()
{
    global $newGlobal;
    initGlobals(); // ?? what will happen to $newGlobal?
}

initGlobals();
$newGlobal = 'I changed the value';
foobar();
```

I think it's pretty clear that using globals is probably the best way to make sure that, if ever there is a bug in the code, the person who is charged with the task of fixing the problem is going to end up in an asylum...
If you don't like to spend the rest of your life in a padded cell, banging your head against the wall, mumbling to yourself *"they're everywhere, but their values are what I want them to be, how could they change? How could they do this to me?"*... in short:

***If you value the sanity, yours or somebody else's, then please, don't use globals.***

---

First: if you have functions that need a certain variable to be set (like in your case a global `$pdo` variable), wouldn't it make more sense to have the caller pass a `PDO` instance to your function in the first place? That way, your code doesn't rely on there being a global variable with the name `$pdo` to exist *and* be a `PDO` instance:

```
function doStuff(PDO $pdo, $foo, $bar)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

But really, it sounds like within your code, certain functions are starting to cluster: you have a series of DB-related functions that all require the same connection (represented by a `PDO` object).
That, to me, sounds like a good use-case for a class:

```
class MyDBClass
{
    protected $pdo = null; // Here's the connection, hidden from the outside, accessible to all methods in this class
    public function __construct(PDO $db)|
    { // Pass PDO instance once, and store it on the instance
        $this->pdo = $db;
    }

    public function doStuff($foo, $bar)
    { // All methods can now use $this->pdo freely:
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM tableX WHERE foo = :foo AND bar = :bar');
        $stmt->execute(
            array(
                ':foo' => $foo,
                ':bar' => $bar
            )
        );
        return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }
    // Add more methods here
}
// Use like this:
$db = new MyDBClass(new PDO()); // Create PDO instance
$db->doStuff('foo value', 'bar');
```

Comment: I actually deleted my answer as it seems you can set global variables using the `$GLOBALS` array: http://codepad.viper-7.com/RzOz8d I had no idea :-)

Comment: Thank you for your well explained answer. I've never really written my own classes, maybe I should give it a shot. I do however already use OO with pdo, so I'm getting more and more familiar with it. I'm building a little framework, trying to keep it very simple, I can do something like this, is a lot like wp, but looks like this: while (get_posts('page')){echo $row['title'];} As $row is manipulated from the function itself... I wanted to try appraoch this framework with as little OO as possible, but looks like I might have to rethink that... Sure gonna be good practice for me. thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

I won't go into why not to use global variables (read up on it). But just access the `$GLOBALS` array anywhere you need it. You can set and retrieve them:

```
function test() {
    echo $GLOBALS['var']; // 1
    $GLOBALS['var'] = 2;
    $GLOBALS['new_var'] = 'yes';
}

$var = 1;
test();
echo $var; // 2
echo $new_var; // Yes
```